# How to open target/destination url of an Ad in custom chrome tab in android

Tags: ads, google-ad-manager, google-ads-api

When a user clicks on an Ad shown[PublisherAdView is used for showing the Ad] in my App, the target/destination url of that Ad is opened in the chrome app. I would like to show the target/destination url of that Ad in a custom chrome tab within the app, instead of the entire chrome app when a user clicks on the Ad.

Comment: i am also having same issue

Comment: @AdityaTomar Have you found any solution?

Comment: @AdityaTomar I added the click tracking url of the Ad in the App manifest, Now I am able to open the ad in a android webview via the prompt dialog.